# How to make Xamarin Forms Slider from Right to Left

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

By default, Xamarin forms Slider is from Left to Right

I have a requirement where I need this slider starting count from left and moving towards right (Cross platform Android and iOS).

Please can anyone share, how can we achieve this using Xamarin Forms?

[Sample_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyHrY.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one of the smartest thing you can do is to use `Rotation` property

```
<Slider x:Name="slider"
        Maximum="360"
        Rotation="180"/>
```

It will start from Right to Left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default slider but implement your logic in a reverse manner in ValueChanged Event. 
Also for the UI to Appear like its right to left you can set a dark colour MaximumTrackerColour and a light (white color) for MinimumTrackerColour.

Also you can use the ThumbImage as an icon "<" this will give a full look as it is right to left.

The only important point is that implementation of ValueChanged Event which should be in reverse manner.